# T-SQL to pull through everything between : and ; only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to pull through everything after an `:` and before a `;`.
For example my current code is:

```
select Left('{Script.Testdata}', CHARINDEX('; ',('{Script.Testdata}'))-1)
```

This currently pulls `" Leon: My Job"` through data from: `Leon: My Job; New job`

I am looking for this to pull through only My Job instead of Leon: My Job. So everything from the `:` and between the `;` but everything between `;` and `;` not to show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select left(stuff(col, 1, charindex(':', col), ''),
            charindex(';', stuff(col, 1, charindex(':', col), '')) - 1
           )
```

Of course, this gets more complicated if the string may not have `:` or `;`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @var varchar(30)
set @var=' Leon: My Job; New jobs;;;'


select Substring(substring (@var,charindex(':',@var)+1,Len(@var)),0,
CHARINDEX('; ',substring (@var,charindex(':',@var)+1,Len(@var))))
```

Comment: Thank you, however this is still pulling back what is after the ;. for example this pulls back, My Job; New Job. How do I now say to pull through everything up to the ;? so just My Job